# Use regular expression to remove tag

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

how can I replace everything in between < > and the tag itself with a space?

Example:

```
<span class="bold">asdfsdfsda<br />sadfsdfsdf</span>
```

Output:

```
 asdfsdfsda sadfsdfsdf
```

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DON'T PARSE HTML with regex. If this in a onetime controlled situation, then this would do:

Here it is in ruby. Change it based upon your tool.

```
myline = '<span class="bold">asdfsdfsda<br />sadfsdfsdf</span>'
myline.gsub(/<[^<]*>/," ")
```